# Mysql: user defined variable in Insert statement

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use following mysql code to insert on column whose name is decided on some value. It gives me error that "some_percent" unknown column 'some_percent' in 'field list'

```
set @SplitState = `some_percent`;
SET @ID = uuid();
INSERT INTO `rspca_donations`(`id`, `@SplitState`) values (@ID, '100');
```

Can someone please suggest correct way?

Comment: Is there a column defined in the `rspca_donations` table called `some_percent`

Comment: You cannot use variables to refer to column or table names. The closest thing you can do is construct the whole query in a variable, then use `PREPARE stmt FROM @query` (followed by `EXECUTE stmt` and `DROP PREPARE stmt`).

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a user variable to represent a column name in this way.  One option here would be to use a prepared statement in MySQL:

```
SET @SplitState = 'some_percent';
SET @ID = UUID();
SET @sql = CONCAT('INSERT INTO rspca_donations (id, ', @SplitState, ') VALUES (?, 100)');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt USING @ID;
```

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen, Thanks. It works for two columns. But I have long list of  fields to be inserted in my real code.

Comment: That sounds like a good topic for another question, my answer is intended to answer what you actually asked above.